# sign in to specific domain on mobile device

Tags: salesforce1-app

How do I sign in to Salesforce 1 through my jobs specific domain On my android smartphone? I work for GE and I'm not sure if I need to use my mobile browser or the mobile application, Salesforce 1?

Comment: How do I add it to the mobile app?

Answer (score 0):

You could use either.  You can access your domain specific url with the mobile browser, or add it to the mobile app.